# Why do I get RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument in pytorch?

Tags: python, cuda, pytorch

Recently I've frequently been getting `RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument` when calling functions like `torch.cholesky` e.g.:

```py
import torch
a = torch.randn(3, 3, device="cuda:0")
a = torch.mm(a, a.t()) # make symmetric positive-definite
torch.cholesky(a)
```

This works fine if I use `device="cpu"` instead. This error isn't very descriptive, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that this error was because the machine I'm running things on has CUDA 10 installed now, but I just installed pytorch as `pip install torch`. From their [website](https://pytorch.org/), the proper way to install with `pip` and CUDA 10 is `pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`.